# PTIJ: Hadar walks in and we're super happy. Why?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

A song that I often hear at this time of year (sometimes sung to [this tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChYeb8ACjqw)) contains the lyrics:

> משנכנס הדר מרבין בשמחה
>
> When Hadar walks in, we increase joy.

(This seems to be based on a variant text of the gemara in [Ta'anit 29a](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.29a.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).)

So, what is it about [Hadar, King of Edom and husband of Mehetabel,](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.36.39?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that makes us so happy when he walks in?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Note: This question is especially relevant in Israel, where many of the locals pronounce ה virtually indistinguishably from א.

Comment: I don't believe Hadar actually exists. הדר אמר רבא לאו מילתא היא. "Hadar," said Rava, "is nothing"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because he owed you a new door frame! Now that he's here, he'll finally pay up! Everyone knows that *mezuzah, chovas Hadar.*

Comment: That’s from Bava Metzi’a 101a, if you’re curious.

Answer (score 11):

משנכנס הדר is referring to Hadar entering into the Land of Israel. The reason why we rejoice over this is that the Talmud (Ketubot 110b) tells us that as long as Hadar remains outside of Israel it is as if he has engaged in idolatry (כל הדר בחו"ל כאילו עובד עבודת כוכבים). It is only once he enters the Land of Israel that he is considered a good Jew. Thus we rejoice for him as we would for anyone who properly repents.

Answer (score 9):

You're translating it wrong. It's:

> From when the resident walks in, Marvin is happy.

But [Marvin](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_the_Paranoid_Android) is *never* happy. Which means that the resident never walks in: he stays outside. Thus, [Wonko](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/The_Outside_of_the_Asylum) really *was* sane.

Comment: Of course! [Shnayim Ve'arba'im - mi yodeya?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1641/shnayim-vearbaim-mi-yodeya)

Answer (score 3):

[According to many mefarshim, the pesukim about the 8 kings of Edom were written prophetically, and Hadar died shortly before Shaul became king.  (Other say that they ruled before the time of Moshe.)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65772/11532)

According to the first explanation, when Hadar came, it meant we were going to have a king soon.  That's a good reason to celebrate.

Answer (score 3):

This is because Hadar is one of the 2 comedians mentioned in [Mishlei 31:25](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Mishlei/31.25#e0n7):

> עֹז־וְהָדָ֥ר לְבוּשָׁ֑הּ וַ֝תִּשְׂחַ֗ק לְי֣וֹם אַחֲרֽוֹן׃
>
> When Oz or Hadar make embarrassing jokes (Lebusha), you will laugh until the end of days.

Therefore, obviously we will be happy when Hadar comes in!

The only question is why Oz is not included.  To this we can answer that although Oz was in before, [Oz came out in 1939](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz_(1939_film)), so he was no longer included by the Gemara, which had Ruach Hakodesh that it would no longer apply.

Comment: But are we allowed to be happy? This sounds like Hadar is making Leitzanus.

Answer (score 0):

Hadar owned the first Etrog tree. The etrog is called פרי עץ הדר - the fruit of the tree belonging to Hadar.

What's the connection of Succot and this time of year that we should sing about this tree? It's simple - around this time of the year is when the etrogim begin to grow.

Comment: I thought that esrogim grow all year, and even from year to year, without a break?

Comment: I'll do some research on that. News to me..

Comment: @Uber_Chacham Of interest - http://delphiresearchgroup.com/b2evolution/index.php?title=things_i_ve_learned_about_growing_etrog&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1

Comment: I assumed that because of the gemara about pri hadar mishana l'shana, but it could be that new ones only start growing in the spring (that would make sense, as the fruit grows from what starts as flowers.

Comment: @Uber_Chacham I would need to look at that Gemara. But, I sense that it's a Midrash. Even if it isn't, it's a "play on words", as the word *hadar* doesn't actually mean this.

Comment: They definitely do grow for years if you don't pick them, I've seen it myself, and that is how they are able to get huge ones. The gemara uses the drasha to prove which fruit is the pri eitz hadar, as only esrogim can stay on the tree growing for years on end.